# Blender won't render any bump maps

Tags: shaders

So, I've recently sculpted a head, now I've added eyeballs. But the eyeballs won't render my bump map even when i connect it to displacement
[image: Viewer rendering the bump node]

[image: Bump Node Setup]

[image: Node Setup]

Comment: If that's really the case, please report that to the official bug tracker: https://developer.blender.org/ : or go to *Help Menu > Report a bug*.

Comment: Why is there a *Viewer* node in your material and why is the output of the *Principled BSDF* not connected to the *Material Output*?

Comment: whoops! almost forgot to remove that, thanks rjg